# Faster way to sum all values of a hashtable

Tags: powershell

What is the faster way to sum all values of a hashtable?

```
$a = @{}
$a.Add("Test1",1)
$a.Add("Test2",2)
$a.Add("Test3",3)
```

Expected result : 6

Something like that but it doesn't work :

```
$a.GetEnumerator() | %{($_.Value | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum}
```

I am going to create a hashtable with more than 10 000 entries so I need the faster way.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Measure-Object` is about twice as fast as enumerating and adding the values.

Proof:

```
PS C:\> $a = @{}
PS C:\> for ($i=1; $i -lt 50000; $i++) { $a["$i"] = (Get-Random) % 5 }
PS C:\> 1..5 | % {
>>   Measure-Command {
>>     $total = 0
>>     $a.GetEnumerator() | % { $total += $_.value }
>>   } | select -Expand TotalMilliseconds
>> }
>>
1075,2542
1081,5379
1082,1324
1074,9834
1076,5663
PS C:\> 1..5 | % {
>>   Measure-Command {
>>     ($a.Values | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum
>>   } | select -Expand TotalMilliseconds
>> }
>>
577,9536
565,8076
579,8534
572,4747
568,8108
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this be faster since you shouldnt need to use `GetEnumerator()`

```
($a.Values | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum
```

If not, I think you could combine the best of both the answers here

Answer (score 0):

```
(measure-command {
$Sum = 0
$a = @{}
$sum += ($a.Test = 1)
$sum += ($a.Test2 = 2)
$sum += ($a.Test3 = 3)
}).TotalMilliseconds


(Measure-Command {
$a = @{}
$a.Add("Test1",1)
$a.Add("Test2",2)
$a.Add("Test3",3)
}).TotalMilliseconds


0.2585
0.4121
```

The first method is faster, and you get $sum accumulated in-stream.

Answer (score 0):

Invoke-Expression ($a.Values -join '+')